# How to get the line number of scenario in cucumber using the event publisher

Tags: java, cucumber

I have written an event publisher on "TestCaseStarted". However it return the wrong line number when I am trying to access its location. I am using below code and feature file.

Expected Line number should be 4 but I am getting value as 13

**Feature File**

```
 Feature: to test a sample test case

  @tc1
  Scenario Outline: sc1
    Given    user has waited for "1" seconds and clicked checkboxes
    |button_id|
    |a        |
    |b        |
    When  user has to enter"<Value>"
    Then validates that the scenarios completes successfully
    Examples:
    |Value    |
    |3        |
    |5        |
```

**Code Snippet**

```
private void EHTestCaseStarted(TestCaseStarted event) {
    String ffPath = event.getTestCase().getUri().getPath();
    String scnType = event.getTestCase().getKeyword();
    Location loc = event.getTestCase().getLocation();
    int scnLine = event.getTestCase().getLocation().getLine();
    int scnCol = event.getTestCase().getLocation().getColumn();

    if (scnType.equalsIgnoreCase("Scenario Outline")) {
        parseGherkin(ffPath, scnLine, scnCol);
    } else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.cucumber/cucumber-core/4.7.2/cucumber/api/TestCase.html) it should be

`event.getTestCase().getLine()`

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1711) . It may provide you (kind of out of the box) what you are trying to do

Comment: it is a deprecated function in latest cucumber versions. Even though it gives the same result as above i.e. 13

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a `Scenario Outline` the actual scenario is defined by the line of the concrete `Example` used in the outline. So the line number is correct.

If you need the parent of a scenario, you can use the `TestSourceParsed` evnet to access the hierarchy the test cases are in.